# How do I pair a yn660 speedlight with the yn560-tx transmitter

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-flash

I can't get the yn560-tx to control my new yn660 light.

The flash fires on test. So it is working.

If I push "act" I can test fire the flash from the transmitter, so they do connect, but I can't pair them for controlling flash from transmitter.

I have figured out how to change hz/fn to match and group/channel. They are synced up.

How do I get the transmitter to control the flash.

I really appreciate any input, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Additional - I am in "M TX" mode. I discovered that in "multi TX" mode I can control the flash from the transmitter, but it's highest power setting is only 1/4. So again I see that the transmitter and flash are working together, just not how I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for anyone else who is confused by this - after extensively messing around with settings it turns out that the flash should be in "RX" mode not "TX". I had the impression from the instructons that it was "TX", but apparently I picked it up wrong. It works just fine like that.

I hope this helps anyone else who got that wrong. I tried practically every setting on both transmitter and flash before finding this.